# «Цена штрафа» - можно ли так сказать?

Tags: употребление-слов

Доброго времени суток :) Недавно столкнулась с употреблением словосочетания «цена штрафа». При этом, говорящий уверял меня, что в силу того, что «штраф» это наказание, употребление этого слова в сочетании со словом «цена» уместно и правильно. В моем понимании слово «штраф» по своей природе является аналогом слова «тариф» и поэтому употребление его в сочетании со словом «цена» звучит как «масло масленное». Имеет ли право на жизнь словосочетание «цена штрафа» или это все же тавтология?

Answer (score 3):

Согласна с Вами, выражение некорректно. Прямое значение слова цена-денежное или иное количественное выражение стоимости товара или услуги .

Штраф-денежное взыскание как мера материального воздействия на лицо

Штраф не является услугой или товаром, у него нет цены, есть величина, сумма: "Позвольте узнать сумму штрафа", "Величина штрафа зависит от...".

Следовательно, нарушена лексическая сочетаемость.

Answer (score 2):

Штраф не аналогичен тарифу, штраф - это денежное взыскание, а тариф - это ставка, норма оплаты чего-н. Существует выражение "штрафные тарифы" - особые нормы оплаты (в качестве  экономических санкций за невыполнение договорных обязательств).

А вот  "цена и стоимость штрафа" звучит весьма странно, не хотелось бы, чтобы такие выражения вошли в наш язык (пока они фиксируются, скорее,  в разговорной речи). Слово "цена" многозначно, но всегда соотносится с тем, что мы приобретаем, а не теряем. Будем надеяться, что оно не будет обозначать свою противоположность.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за Ваши ответы.
София, Вы абсолютно правы относительно замечания о тарифе. Я выразилась некорректно. Следовало скорее написать не "аналогичен тарифу", а "нечто, как правило, имеющее денежное выражение".

Answer (score 2):

правильнее было бы - сумма штрафа. если только, зная уровень коррупции, речь не шла о "цене вопроса" ;)